# Linking manuals from Homebrew

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew

Whenever I install a software with Homebrew and I try to view the manual I get an error stating:

> No manual entry for `<name of program>`.

As an example, `wget`: when I type

```
$ man wget
No manual entry for wget
```

So, I'm wondering how to link the man pages so I can view them with the command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you installed Homebrew with standard install directories, i.e. relatives to `/usr/local`,
there are 2 commands to register the binaries and man files to be used:

```
/usr/bin/sudo -s
echo /usr/local/bin >/etc/paths.d/homebrew
echo /usr/local/share/man >/etc/manpaths.d/homebrew
exit
```

Replace `/usr/local` with `/opt/homebrew` on Apple Silicon Macs.

If you are using `bash` or `zsh` as your actual shell, you will have to enter one simple command to take into account these 2 environment modifications:

```
. /etc/profile
```

If you want to learn more how these 2 directories are used under
MacOS X, read:

```
man path_helper
```

Anyway, you don't have to modify these pathes at the level of every users inside of their `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` because they are read at each shell level which is a total waste.
This is a much too common error and leading to too many problems of clean system maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

Add `eval "$(brew shellenv)"` into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`

#### see `brew shellenv` output:

```
$ brew shellenv
export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew";
export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar";
export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew";
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}";
export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:";
export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
```

#### `man brew` and find keywords `shellenv`:

> `shellenv` Print export statements. When run in a shell, this installation of Homebrew will be added to your PATH, MANPATH, and INFOPATH.
>
> ```
>    The variables HOMEBREW_PREFIX, HOMEBREW_CELLAR and HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY are also exported to avoid querying them multiple
> ```
>
> times. To help guarantee idempotence, this
> command produces no output when Homebrew´s bin and sbin directories are first and second respectively in your PATH. Consider
> adding evaluation of this command´s output
> to your dotfiles (e.g. ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.zprofile) with: eval "$(brew shellenv)"